# active record issue to return array (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table called **uploaded_files** in my database where I have the following fields:

> id, file_name, upload_id, filetype_id

this last field (filetype_id) is a Foreign Key to a table called **filetype** where I have these fields:

> id, filetype_desc

I'm trying to create a method in my model to return all the fields in table **uploaded_files**, in an array following this structure:

```
array(
            'file_type_1'  => array(
                'id'            => 1,
                'file_name' => "lalala.txt",
                'upload_id'     => $uploadId,
                'filetype_id'   => 1
            ),
            'file_type_2' => array(
                'id'            => 1,
                'file_name' => "lelele.txt",
                'upload_id'     => $uploadId,
                'filetype_id'   => 2
            ),
            'file_type_3' => array(
                'id'            => 1,
                'file_name' => "blabla.txt",
                'upload_id'     => $uploadId,
                'filetype_id'   => 3
            ),
    );
}
```

Until now, I came to this:

```
public function get_UploadedFilesFromUploadId($uploadId){
        //$query = "select * from uploaded_files where upload_id =".$uploadId;
        $query = $this->db->get_where('uploaded_files', array(
                                                            'upload_id' => $uploadId
                                                        )
                                    );
        return $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Comment: And what seems to be the problem? What have you tried that has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('uploaded_files', array(
                                                            'upload_id' => $uploadId
                                                        )
                                    );
$res =  $this->db->query($query);

$result = array();
foreach ($res->result_array() as $row)
{
   $key = 'file_type_'.$row['filetype_id']; 
   $result[$key] = $row;
}
```

Comment: I'm still having a problem: Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php

Comment: do you think there's a problem with the way I'm building the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('uploaded_files',array('upload_id' => $uploadId));
foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
echo $row->filetype_id;
}
```

I think it's help you.